# Django customize ForeignKey way of instances returnment

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a need to create custom field, that is very similar to a *ForeignKey* field but has specific logic. Two main tasks are:

1. Each related model of this *CustomForeignKey* has regular *ForeignKey* field to the model itself and my purpose is to return one of this instances depending on some parameter (date for example). Maybe it would be more clear with some example:

   ```
   class Author(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
       surname = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
       publication = CustomForeignKey(Publication)

   class Publication(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
       text = models.TextField()
       date = models.DateTimeField()
       source = models.ForeigKey('self', related_name='references')
   ```

   I want calls to `SomeAuthor.publication` be performed like `SomePublication.references.order_by('date').first()`. Real goal is more difficult, but the sense is nearly the same.
2. Second thing is about lookups. When I filter objects by this *CustomForeignKey*, I would like to have same logic as in previous point. So `Author.objects.filter(publication__title = 'Some Title')` should make filtering by the fist object ordered by date from `references` related manager.

I read the documentation about [creating custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/) in django, but there are no good examples about custom relational fields. In `django.db.models.fields.related` as well, I didn't find which methods should I redefine to achieve my goal. There are `to_python` and `from_db_value`, but they are used only in regular fields, not related ones.

Maybe someone had more experince with custom relational fields, so I would be tankful for any advice!

Comment: What about inheriting the `ForeignKey` class ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Yes, ForeignKey inheritance is propably a solution and I know about it, but I can't recognize which methods should be redefined inside it, that's why I am asking